# CMake custom target alias

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to add alias to custom target? like it works for libraries

```
add_library(Upstream::lib1 ALIAS lib1)
```

I did not found such ability for custom targets https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#alias-targets

Comment: Nope. But why do you need it?

Comment: I see. I wanted it just for a syntax sugar. And it would be legitimate to expect a `ALIAS` for `add_custom_target()`

Comment: Not really. My guess: aliased targets are good for `target_link_libraries` and exports. You just can't use custom targets w/ this command as well as "export" them, so no need for aliases.

Comment: What is "export" and why to "export"?

Comment: Please read CMake docs [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages).

Comment: Thank you for direct link. I never used this facility and have no needs in the near future. But it looks good.

Comment: It's inevitable if you have a codebase spread out of few repos and with deps on each other.

Comment: may be. but currently i build a bundle of programs adding subdirectories in a root CMakeLists and it works fine.